# calling id from service in Angular 7

Tags: angular, web-services

And I have a web api call. But with a id.

I have this:

```
private readonly apiDiploma = 'api/support/teachers/personId';
```

Then I call this method like this:

```
  return this.http.get<DiplomaModel>(this.apiDiploma, spinnerMessage).pipe(map(result => result.documents));
```

But this doesn't work. But for example if I do this:

```
private readonly apiDiploma = 'api/support/teachers/1001/diploma/';
```

so the PersonId hardcoded. It works.

So what I have to change?

Thank you

this is the api method:

```
private readonly apiDiploma = 'api/support/teachers/personId/diploma/';
```

So I need the PersonId from:

```
export class TeacherSearchModel {
  personId: number;
  name: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
  bsn: string;
  registerNumber: string;
}
```

But if I do this:

```
 private readonly apiDiploma = 'api/support/teachers/${personId}/diploma';
```

and then this:

```
  getDiplomaDocumentList(spinnerMessage?: string): Observable<DocumentListModel> {
            // Get and return diploma info from backend


            return this.http.get<DiplomaModel>(this.apiDiploma,  spinnerMessage).pipe(map(result => result.documents));
        }
```

I still get errors:

```
GET http://localhost:6597/api/support/teachers/$%7BpersonId%7D/diploma 400 (Bad Request)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:3243
push.../../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
```

Comment: Self explanatory isn't it? You have to concatenate/interpolate the string parts and the value to create the passed in URL string at the time you make the call. The other issue is that your hard coded url string does **not** end in `diploma`, the string you tested does. The url is thus made up of 3 parts: `'api/support/teachers/' + personId + ' /diploma/'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `personId` is a variable which contains a person id, just concat `personId` to your URL: `'api/support/teachers/' + personId;` or `'api/support/teachers/${personId}';`.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a property called `personId`, you can assign value to it based on your need / logic. replace personid in the `apiDiploma` using `personId` when making a service call using es6 template literal `${this.apiDiploma}${this.personid}`

```
private readonly apiDiploma = 'api/support/personid/diploma/';

personiId = '1234'; //you can change the personid dynamically.

return this.http.get<DiplomaModel>(this.apiDiploma.replace('personid',this.personid), spinnerMessage).pipe(map(result => result.documents));
```

Comment: Thank you. but the call to the web api looks like this:  private readonly apiDiploma = 'api/support/teachers/personId/diploma/';

Comment: Is diploma a static string or dynamic value like personid?

Comment: your question doesn't seems to say that whether the 'diploma' is static or dynamic value?

Comment: Just follow my answer it will work, you need not to add ${personid}